# Tensorflow InternalError: Unable to get element as bytes when training

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I've started learning Tensorflow and Python, and I've reached a point where I'm kind of lost.

I'm trying to train a model that predicts Amazon's stars from its reviews using [Xiang Zhang's dataset](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0Bz8a_Dbh9Qhbfll6bVpmNUtUcFdjYmF2SEpmZUZUcVNiMUw1TWN6RDV3a0JHT3kxLVhVR2M).

[Here is the link to the Google Colab notbook that I'm writing.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BtcMELWWy85LSav-XTUFq7SrQOL93vHt)

I'm having  `InternalError: Unable to get element as bytes`

With this context, here are my questions

- What does the error mean? Is a pandas or Tensorflow error? How can I debug it?
- Why does it runs for a while, and then stops?
- The train CSV weights 1.3Gb, is it safe to load it with pandas? It does some kind of buffering behind the scenes? I've seen that you can pass `chunksize` to the `read_csv` function, but how do I use it with the `train_input_fn`?

Thanks in advance!